Incrementally number blocks of rows based on time limits in another column
I have a df with 3 fields as shown below, I'd like for shift number to incrementally generate based on pick start time.
If pick start time between 22:00 and 0600, thats shift 1; then iterate for all values in pick start to label shift number incrementally.
day         pick start  shift number
4/17/2024   22:27:08    SHIFT 1
4/17/2024   22:33:08    SHIFT 1
4/18/2024   06:27:08    SHIFT 1
4/18/2024   22:28:09    SHIFT 2
4/18/2024   06:30:00    SHIFT 2

Thanks for your help!

The logic is unclear, please break down your example explaining how each SHIFT is obtained

Thanks for your response Mozway; each shift runs between 11:00 PM (22:00 military time) and 06:30 AM (06:30 military time) the next day. So I want to iterate over 'pick start' column and if the time value falls between 2200-0630; that's shift 1. The next block of 2200-0630 is shift 2 and so on.

To summarize the logic, a new shift starts at 06:30, so you can subtract 06:30 to each datetime (converted with to_datetime), normalize the date, get the diff and increment the shift based on the change to a new "day" with a cumsum:
date = pd.to_datetime(df['day']+df['pick start'], format='%m/%d/%Y%H:%M:%S')

new = date.sub(pd.Timedelta('06:30:00')).dt.normalize().diff().ge('1d')

df['shift number'] = 'SHIFT ' + new.cumsum().add(1).astype(str)

Output:
         day pick start shift number
0  4/17/2024   22:27:08      SHIFT 1
1  4/17/2024   22:33:08      SHIFT 1
2  4/18/2024   06:27:08      SHIFT 1
3  4/18/2024   22:28:09      SHIFT 2
4  4/18/2024   06:30:00      SHIFT 2

Intermediates:
         day pick start                date        sub('06:30')  normalize   diff  gt('1d')  cumsum shift number
0  4/17/2024   22:27:08 2024-04-17 22:27:08 2024-04-17 15:57:08 2024-04-17    NaT     False       0      SHIFT 1
1  4/17/2024   22:33:08 2024-04-17 22:33:08 2024-04-17 16:03:08 2024-04-17 0 days     False       0      SHIFT 1
2  4/18/2024   06:27:08 2024-04-18 06:27:08 2024-04-17 23:57:08 2024-04-17 0 days     False       0      SHIFT 1
3  4/18/2024   22:28:09 2024-04-18 22:28:09 2024-04-18 15:58:09 2024-04-18 1 days      True       1      SHIFT 2
4  4/18/2024   06:30:00 2024-04-18 06:30:00 2024-04-18 00:00:00 2024-04-18 0 days     False       1      SHIFT 2

